# Android action bar batch selection for versions prior to 3.0

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a `ListView` for which I want to enable batch selection. For android 3.0 and above I've added a modal multi choice to the `ListView` and set the multi choice mode listener.

How can I do the same for android versions prior to 3.0 (with or without a third party library) ? I've looked at ActionBarSherlock but I haven't found this feature in any samples nor searching for information on the web.

PS: When the user clicks an item in the `ListView` I want to perform a different action, so it needs to be long-click for batch selection (or a single item selection).

Versions prior to 3.0 that go back to API 7.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the type functionality/result you are looking for? Or do you need radio buttons? I'll edit this reply with code/detail if this is the type thing you need.

[image]